# Which header file should be added to use thread in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I know that C++ supports thread. 
On the Windows platform, using `#include <thread>` works fine.

Does `#includes <thread>` work on Linux, or should some different header file should be used?

Comment: Your are missing the concept of iso standard. If it is in the standard, it should be supported no matter the OS. I'm saying "should be" because some compiler vendors don't support all of the standard features. Thus, is not about if OS supports a C++ feature but rather if the compiler you are using supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on version of C++ you are using. Shortly it boils down to version of compiler (gcc/g++ I suppose) you are using.

As far as I am concerned in C++ x11 threads are already built into standard library (I think that if you are alredy using thread header you are using latest C++ standard, at least on Windows) so probably you should only check if you Linux C++ compiler supports it. If not you can try upgrading it.

But if you are using older version on language, you will need to use platform depended libraries and headers. For Linux it will be pthread `#include <pthread.h>`. If you are forced to use older version of language, you can also take a look at Boost libraries which abstract away threads and expose uniform interface. Examples [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html)

Comment: It seems an old version I am using now, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

[`#include <thread>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) is part of the standard C++ library. That means it *should* behave the same on any platform you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `<thread>` is the standard header (i.e. provided by the C++ standard), it is the right one to include on **every** platform.